# combine basic code to work for iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nstimer

Ive been messing around with the UILabel code and NSTimer and WordArray, and have still not been able to figure out how to code them the way i need them.

I need to have the UIlabel change every 1min, which i figured out, but I also need the UILabel to change to the next word in a list of 100 words, can anyone show me an example of this code using just 3 or 4 words so I know the order I must do this in? Thanks.

```
UILabel *scoreLabel = [ [UILabel alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.bounds.size.width / 2), 0.0, 150.0, 43.0) ];
scoreLabel.textAlignment =  UITextAlignmentCenter;
scoreLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
scoreLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
scoreLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" size:(36.0)];
[self addSubview:scoreLabel];
scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", score];

myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60 target:self selector:@selector(changeLabel) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; 

-(void)changeLabel { 
    scoreLabel.text = [wordArray objectAtIndex:cntr]; 
    cntr++; 
    if(cntr==100) [myTimer invalidate]; 
}
```

Comment: Tip: When you enter code, remember to highlight it and click the 'code' icon. It will make it much easier to read your code examples.

Answer (score 0):

wordArray is an NSMutableArray

```
NSMutableArray *wordArray;
```

in your header file, and

```
wordArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObects:@"Several",@"Words",@"Here",nil];
```

OR

```
wordArray = [NSMutableArray array];
[wordArray addObject:@"Several"];
[wordArray addObject:@"Words"];
[wordArray addObject:@"Here"];
```

as examples to add to it.

Comment: Alright thanks and do i have to link each invidual wordArray word to the NSTimer? Or does having [wordArray objectAtIndex:cntr]; control when they all change?

Comment: Are you adding all the words one time in one place?  Or are you gradually adding words depending on other factors?

Comment: I am adding all the words at once, and then want the program to go through each one every 60 seconds across the screen. But eventually I will add more, but im assuming I just edit the program and reset it when i do that.

Comment: Yeah then you can just leave [wordArray objectAtIndex:cntr];  and as long as you have 100 words in there it will work fine. Remember to set cntr = 0; in your main code before you create the timer.